# Which picture does the ORA-01830 error message refer to?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

> ORA-01830: **date format picture** ends before converting entire input string

[About the error message](http://www.dba-oracle.com/sf_ora_01830_date_format_picture_ends_before_converting_entire_input_string.htm).

I am confused. Which picture is the error message talking about? All I provided was a date.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "format picture" refers to the format mask.  If you are doing an explicit conversion using the `TO_DATE` function, the format picture is the second argument

```
to_date( input_string, format_picture )
```

i.e.

```
to_date( '2011-01-01 01:23:45', 'YYYY-MM-DD' )
```

In this case, the format picture is the "YYYY-MM-DD".  This expression raises the ORA-01830 error because the input string contains more data than the format picture is capable of handling.

If, on the other hand, you are doing an implicit conversion, the format picture refer's to the session's `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` which Oracle uses in its own implicit `TO_DATE` call.

Answer (score 3):

This means that you have provided more than just a date.  Perhaps an extra space, or you have provided a time but are asking it to format just a date.

> 05/06/2009 11:08:49 PM
>
> alter session set nls_date_format='DD/MM/YYYY';
>
> sqlldr . . .
>
> ORA-01830 date format picture ends before converting entire input
>   string

Comment: yes, I understand the problem, but what does **format picture** refer to?

Comment: "DD/MM/YYYY" is the format picture in the sample.

Comment: I prefer to use alter session set nls_date_format = 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'